# Why is this code returning the same average number of comparisons for both linear and binary search?

Tags: python, search

This came out of a series of questions during an A-Level computer science lesson.

The task was to modify an existing, badly written program to accomplish several tasks.

The task for this one was to modify the program to compare the time efficiency of each search by changing both `linearSearch` and `binarySearch` to return a count variable that increments by one every time that a comparison is made. Then create a function to do a series of tests on lists of varying lengths and outputting the average number of comparisons of each.

The issue with the code below is a logic error that results in the average being the **exact same** for each set. I have tried making modifications to the variable identifiers, but it has not helped.

```
def linearSearch(searchList, searchVal):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(searchList)):
        count += 1
        if searchList[i] == searchVal:
            return i
    return count

def binarySearch(searchList, searchVal):
    start = 0
    count = 0
    end = len(searchList) - 1
    while start <= end:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        count += 1
        if searchList[mid] == searchVal:
            return mid
        elif searchList[mid] < searchVal:
            start = mid + 1
        elif searchList[mid] > searchVal:
            end = mid - 1
    return count

def generateList(limit):
    list = []
    for i in range(limit):
        list.append(i)
    return list

import random

def test():
    testType = 1
    while testType <= 5:
        linearTestNo = 0
        binaryTestNo = 0
        length = 10**testType
        searchList = generateList(length)
        linearCountTotal = 0
        binaryCountTotal = 0
        while linearTestNo <= 100 and binaryTestNo <= 100:
            x = random.randint(0,length-1)
            linearCountTotal += linearSearch(searchList, x)
            linearTestNo += 1
            binaryCountTotal += binarySearch(searchList, x)
            binaryTestNo += 1
        print(f"Linear Search took {linearCountTotal/100} comparisons on average for a list of {length} items")
        print(f"Binary Search took {binaryCountTotal/100} comparisons on average for a list of {length} items")
        testType += 1


test()
```

At the suggestion of my teacher, I split the `TestNo` variables into one for each, even though it wouldn't change anything. I did so, and the error continues to happen.

Comment: I'm confused. You have both methods running in a single `while` loop with a single timer. How could they _not_ give the same result?

Comment: Check to see what each search function is actually returning.

Comment: Replace `return mid` by `break` and your test output will make sense. For consistency sake, make a similar change in the linear search function. It really doesn't make a sense to return the item in part of the function and the count in another part.

Answer (score 1):

upon checking your code line by line, following are some suggestions

1. The both functions `linearSearch` and `binarySearch` are returning length of the list if the search value is not found. I know the search value will be part of list but this is not suggested to find time efficiency. Because you find time efficiency for worst case scenario.
2. To find time efficiency, theoretically you count number of execution cycle per instruction at processor level. but to check practically you need to include timing functions. check [time in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

As this is your assigned work I am not sharing correct code, please work on the suggestions :)

Comment: The assignment says to count the number of comparisons, not get the actual timing. When doing complexity analysis, it's common to abstract away low-level differences.

Comment: okay still it should be for worst case scenario, i.e the search element not in list. and for linear search it is straight length of list and for binary search no of divisions of 2 of length of list. right ?

Comment: Right. They need to return `count` when successful, not the found value.